# How to store BitBucket webhook post content to a file using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, webhooks

I am using a Generic webhook plugin in Jenkins to get BitBucket payload data.

Screenshot: 
[image: Generic webhook Jenkins screenshot]
I am successfully getting info for about 60% of the post content, however in some cases payload data is quite large and I am running into an error such as:

```
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

To getaway from this error, is there a way to store post content data to a text file using Jenkins and then read info from the file? Any pointers will help

Comment: Webhook trigger successfully works up to a size of 500000 characters per request, and then it throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Form too large: 600000 > 500000". I suspect your issue is somewhere else.

Comment: The way I worked around my issue was to parse specific fields that I am interested in rather than having all contributing variables. Don't think that it is the right way but atleast that works as a workaround (and I don't see that qualifying as an answer here). Haven't figured out the actual issue yet.